# using COM port with Matlab online

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am trying to send some data via the com port using Arduino and trying to read them using Matlab. I do not have Matlab installed with me and hence I am using the Matlab online. Now everytime I try to read the COM port I get errors stating that the COM port is not available.

```
Error using serial/fopen (line 72)
Open failed: Port: COM1 is not available. No ports are available.
```

Can't I access the COM port using Matlab online? Is there any other way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB Online cannot be used with hardware. See MATLAB Online [Specifications and Limitations](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-online/limitations.html)

> - MATLAB Online cannot interact with hardware, including devices used    for image acquisition and instrument control.
> - Creating custom user interfaces, such as those built with GUIDE, is    not supported.
> - Windows-specific components like COM are not supported.
> - xlsread and xlswrite will work in basic mode.
> - Using the MEX command to build C/C++ or Fortran MEX-files is not    supported.
> - Files larger than 16 MB cannot be uploaded on MATLAB Online.
> - The graphical interface to the profiler is not supported.
> - Use of the shell escape bang (!) command is not supported.